# asp.net mvc with BLToolkit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, orm

I just want to know is there any tutorial or instructions of creating project in asp.net mvc (2 or 3) with BLToolkit (Busines Logic tool for .net) http://www.bltoolkit.net/Home.ashx

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 as my ORM, but people are talking about BLT.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use some more lightweight ORM tool I suggest you rather start flirting with with one of the following:

- Dapper-dot-net
- Massive
- PetaPoco

Depending on your project's requirements you'll be able to decide for the right one.

These are much simpler and very lightweight and even faster than BLToolkit which lacks usable documentation especially since it's complexity is very high. Support is also very very bad unless you speak Russian.